# Как проверить, есть ли файл в Addressable?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно проверить, есть ли файл с определенным названием в Addressable.
То, что я пробовал:

```
public bool AddressableResourceExists(object key)
{
    foreach (var l in Addressables.ResourceLocators)
    {
        IList<IResourceLocation> locs;
        if (l.Locate(key, typeof(TextAsset), out locs))
           return true;
    }
    return false; // всегда возвращает false
}
```

```
var selectMany = Addressables.ResourceLocators.OfType<ResourceLocationMap>()
    .SelectMany(locationMap =>
        locationMap.Locations.Keys.Select(key => key.ToString())
); // всегда пустой
```